Touchpad scrolling and keyboard working Ubuntu 22
I am encountering the following challenges

the touchpad is not working (I have tested using the mouse and still the same problem) specifically when I try scrolling, it Automatically instead zooms the page
the keyboard is not working, i tried to open the terminal using hotkeys still no results

I last used the PC yesterday and it was just perfect
It's a thinkbook
